# Uploading Image to firebase storage doesnt work with some images when i added progessDialog

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to build a replace profile picture functionality in my code using the codes below.It works fine sometimes.Other times, nothing happens after i select the picture from my gallery(Some images).It appears the select image from gallery activity just crashes after i select the image to upload and the application just terminates in logcat without any error.It used to work fine before i added the progress dialog

```
private void postImage() {

        String path = "userProfiles/" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpeg";
        StorageReference userProfilesRef = storage.getReference(path);
        userProfilesRef.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                downloadUrls = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                final String id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("Male").hasChild(id)){

                             databaseReference.child("Male").child(id).child("downloadUrl").setValue(downloadUrls);
                            databaseReference1.child("Male").child(key).child("downloadUrl").setValue(downloadUrls);

                        }
                        else {

                            databaseReference.child("Female").child(id).child("downloadUrl").setValue(downloadUrls);
                            databaseReference1.child("Female").child(key).child("downloadUrl").setValue(downloadUrls);

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


            }
        });

  /*      userProfilesRef.putFile(filePath).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Upload Failed, Please try again ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });*/
    }



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(filePath)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(this);



    }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Please Wait...");
                mProgressDialog.show();
                resultUri = result.getUri();
                postImage();
                image.setImageURI(resultUri);

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: I'd help you if you had a logcat and a [mcve]

Comment: Please i have edited my code @cricket_007

Comment: I don't see any code edits, just the text. I would be surprised if there is no logcat, but `onCancelled` is empty and `Exception error` is never printed. Try adding more `Log.d` statements yourself to see where your code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
if(mProgressDialog != null)
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

if there is no error so you miss something at your dialog declaration